# Как правильно написать SQL запрос к vtiger crm API

Tags: php, vtiger-api

Всем привет. Нужно получить данные из vTiger CRM. Логика следующая: нужно выбрать все строки, где статус = "В продаже" и название или описание товара LIKE %var%.

Делаю запрос:

```
$vtiger->query('*', 'Products', "productname LIKE '%$name%' OR description LIKE '%$name%' AND cf_1007 = 'В продаже'", null, 50, null);
```

Сразу скажу, использую библиотеку https://github.com/sumocoders/vtiger-api

Как правильно построить данный запрос? Т.е. чтобы выбор был таким, каким он мне нужен? Т.е. чтобы выбирались все товары, которые в продаже и у которых название или описание похоже на переменную?

Comment: Скобки расставь во WHERE - чтобы не сомневаться, что логика соответствует задаче.

Comment: @Akina сделал вот так: `"(productname LIKE '%$name%' OR description LIKE '%$name%') AND cf_1007 = 'В продаже'"` Но теперь вообще кидает исключение

Comment: Сделай подстановку в отдельной переменной, и проверь выводом, что ты в этой переменной получил